# Jexl3 throws exceptions on variable starting with $

Tags: jexl

I'm trying to move from jexl2 to jexl3 and I noticed that it throws exception on variables starting with $. It used to work on jexl2. The problem is that I've been using this extensively everywhere.

This works in jexl2

```
    JexlContext jc = new MapContext();
    jc.set("$a", "A00123" );
    jc.set("r", r );
    Expression e = jexl.createExpression( "r.header.mrn=$a" );
```

But throws this in jexl3:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.jexl3.JexlException$Variable: undefined variable a
```

Is there a workaround or I have no way of moving to jexl3?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I have no other option but rename my variables when they follow after equal sign:

They have introduced the 'startsWith' and 'endsWith' operators '=^' and '=$' and that's why I get the exception